# Apply Sentence Case to string which might contain HTML

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a series of strings which I need to convert to "sentence case", but what makes it more complicated is that the string could have html anchor tags.

One might contain html like this:

```
<a href="/foo">foo</a> is a word. this is another word, and <a href="/bar">bar</a> is another.
```

And I would like to apply sentence case with output as follows:

```
<a href="/foo">Foo</a> is a word. This is another word, and <a href="/bar">bar</a> is another.
```

I can use any solution which utilizes `js` or `vbscript`.

Comment: And what have you tried? Post that code to your question.

Comment: Well with this one I am not sure how to attack the problem, so I guess I need help with logic. I will take a stab at it using regex, but I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Why the vote down? I legitimately wanted help with the logic for this one. Help me understand what about the question is not appropriate and that warrants a down vote.

Comment: @robarwebservices: there are people who mindlessly apply a "no code = downvote" policy. There's nothing you can do for them, so don't worry about it. (I know, I know, easier said than done.) In this case, maybe explicitly start your question by stating that you don't have the faintest idea how to even start attacking the problem?

Comment: @Martha, thanks for the reply and the +3. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking, here is a port of Rion Williams logic to a `vbScript` function. I used a few functions from my own class library, so Including just the needed parts of those as well, for reference.

As Rion said, it is just a start, and will need lots of fine tuning.

```
Function toSentenceCase(byVal x)
    Dim i, r, s, bCapitalize, bInHtml

    bCapitalize = True
    bInHtml = False

    Set r = New regularExpression
    Set s = New adoStream

    For i = 1 To Len(x)
        sChar = Mid(x, i, 1)
        Do
            'If this is any non tag, punctuation or letter or we are in HTML and haven't encountered a closing tag
            If r.test("[^a-zA-Z\?\.\>\\<\!]", sChar) Or (bInHtml And sChar <> ">") Then 
                s sChar
                Exit Do
            End If

            'if we should capitalize, check if we can, and if yes, then capitalize
            If bCapitalize And r.test("[a-zA-Z]", sChar) Then 
                s uCase(sChar)
                bCapitalize = False
                Exit Do
            Else 
                s sChar

                'if this character is '<', then we are in HTML, so ignore these
                If sChar = "<" Then 
                    bInHtml = True
                    Exit Do
                End If

                'if the character is a closing tag '>', then start paying attention again
                If sChar = ">" Then
                    bInHtml = False
                    Exit Do
                End If

                'determine if we hit punctuation to start a new sentence
                If r.test("[\?\!\.]", sChar) Then
                    bCapitalize = True
                    Exit Do
                End If  

            End If 

        Loop While False
    Next

    toSentenceCase = s.Value
End Function 

Class adoStream
    'string builder class. adodb streams are way faster than appending to/editing content of string variables
    Private stream

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()                  
        Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = 2 '2 = text stream
        stream.Open
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        stream.Close
        Set stream = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Default Sub Add(byVal addString) 'add string to existing stream
        stream.WriteText addString
    End Sub

    Public Sub Update(byVal addString) 'update existing stream and set it to a new value. clear existing stream and set it = new value
        Clear
        stream.WriteText addString
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Value 'returns full stream
        stream.Position = 0
        Value = stream.ReadText()
    End Property

    Public Function Clear() 'resets stream
        stream.Position = 0
        Call stream.SetEOS()
    End Function        
End Class


Class regularExpression
    'class containing a set of vbscript regex routines
    Private oRegex
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()                  
        Set oRegex = New RegExp
        oRegex.Global = True    'e.g. findall
        oRegex.IgnoreCase = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Set oRegex = Nothing
    End Sub

    'test
    Public Function test(byVal sPattern, byVal sTestString) 'return t/f
        If isNull(sTestString) Then 
            test = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        oRegex.Pattern = sPattern
        test = oRegex.test(sTestString)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you could build a rather naive approach that simply iterates through the string and flags conditions based on what it encounters (i.e. it sets an `inHtml` flag to indicate that it is in an HTML tag and sets another `shouldCapitalize` flag to determine if it's at the start of a sentence :

```
function titleCaseHtmlSentence(s){
    // A temporary string to hold your results
    var result = '';
    // Iterate through the sentence and check each character to determine if 
    // it is the start of a sentence, ignore this
    var shouldCapitalize = true;
    var inHtml = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        // If this is any non tag, punctuation or letter or we are in HTML
        // and haven't encountered a closing tag
        if(/[^a-zA-Z\?\.\>\\<\!]/.test(s[i]) || (inHtml && s[i] != '>')){
            result += s[i];
            continue;   
        }
        // If we should capitalize, check if we can
        if(shouldCapitalize && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(s[i])){
            // Capitalize this character
            result += s[i].toUpperCase();
            shouldCapitalize = false;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            result += s[i];
            // If this character is '<', then we are in HTML, so ignore these
            if(s[i] == '<'){
                inHtml = true;
                continue;
            }
            // If the character is a closing tag '>', then start paying attention again
            if(s[i] == '>'){
                inHtml = false;
                continue;
            }

            // Determine if we hit punctuation to start a new sentence
            if(/[\?\!\.]/.test(s[i])){
                shouldCapitalize = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I threw it together rather hastily, so I am sure that's far from optimal in any sense, but it should work as [seen in this example](http://jsbin.com/ropaju/edit?js,output).